# Android ViewFlipper Keep the same view after screen timeout

Tags: android, viewflipper

I'm using ViewFlipper in My application and I need to keep the current view when the screen timeout , so when I back to the application after screen timeout I will see the same view not going back to the first view of the ViewFlipper
Any Help?
Thanks

Comment: Post your code that creates/sets up your `ViewFlipper`, as well as any state you save/restore (if you are). You'll have more luck getting an answer that way.